# Copy data from PyObject to float * using boost

Tags: c++, boost-python

This should be easy I think, but I cannot make it work. I want to call a `C++-function` from python. As argument I have an `np-array`. The `C++` looks like this:

```
void foo_python(PyObject *p, const int m, const int n){
    float *data = new float[m*n];
    memcpy(data,PyArray_DATA(p),m*n*sizeof(float));
    delete [] data;
}
```

When I call this from python using

```
hello_ext.foo_python(A,A.shape[0], A.shape[1])
```

I get

```
  error: cannot convert ‘PyObject* {aka _object*}’ to ‘PyArrayObject* {aka tagPyArrayObject*}’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void* PyArray_DATA(PyArrayObject*)’
```

This used to work but came when I included `#include <boost/python/numpy.hpp>`
, which is needed in this function where I return `ndarrays` to python.

```
np::ndarray test() {
    int *data = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i){
        data[i] = i+1;
    }
    p::tuple shape = p::make_tuple(5);
    p::tuple stride = p::make_tuple(sizeof(int));
    p::object own;
    np::dtype dt = np::dtype::get_builtin<int>();
    std::cout << " Here " << std::endl;
    np::ndarray array = np::from_data(data, dt, shape, stride, own);
    cout<<"Selective Multidimensional array :: "<<std::endl << 
    p::extract<char const *>(p::str(array)) << std::endl;
    // delete [] data;
    return array;
}
```

This is the module:

```
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(libhello_ext)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    Py_Initialize();
    boost::python::numpy::initialize();
    def("greet", greet);
    def("sum", sum);
    def("foo_python", foo_python);
    def("test", test);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution I came up with was to replace `PyObject *p` with `np::ndarray &p`. Then I can create a pointer `float *p = reinterpret_cast<float *>(p.get_data())`.

`p` can then be used in `Map` to create an `Eigen::Matrix` using `Map<FMatrix > A(data, m, n);` with

`typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::RowMajor> FMatrix;`